# Android - Firebase Dynamic Social Meta Tags Links on Google +

Tags: android, firebase, google-plus, firebase-dynamic-links

I have an application with dynamic links implemented. I'm making request to get short link with all `socialMetaTagInfo` defined (`socialTitle`, `socialDescription`, `socialImageLink`)

`link` is so far only dummy page with simple and whole request looks like this (I'm not filling more fields):

```
{
    "dynamicLinkInfo": {
        "dynamicLinkDomain": "dl_domain",
        "link": "http://www.my_page.com",
        "androidInfo": {
            "androidPackageName": string
        },
        "socialMetaTagInfo": {
            "socialTitle": string,
            "socialDescription": string,
            "socialImageLink": string
        }
    }
}
```

When I share result short link on Facebook I can see nice post with image, title and description. However when I share the link via Google + only link is visible without social fields. (Same for Slack for example).

Do I have to create my fallback page first? Or am I doing something wrong? I just want to know how to display the image, title and description in other social apps (pages).

Answer (score -1):

Title,Desc,Images are the additional meta tags which is added to your Dynamic links. 
Apps like Facebook, Twitter, Google+ will be identifying the meta data from your url and load it in the UI. 
It may fail to load if the Image size is large or if Google+ app is not coded to handle it.

Comment: *"or if Google+ app is not coded to handle it."* I think that is the question being asked here, so this is not a very useful answer unless it explains *how* the Google+ app should be coded to handle it.